# Custom Salesforce report for revenue splits

Tags: lightning, reporting

I would like to set up a new custom report in Salesforce (Lightning), that shows the sales revenue for each sales representative in the second half of 2023.

The basics are pretty straight forward and my report looks like this:

[image]

The tricky part is showing the consolidated revenue for each Sales Manager (SM) for "revenue splits" - meaning, that in theory each SM can be part of another SM's deal.

Our Opportunities have dedicated fields for those cases:

- SM_1
- Revenue1 (total revenue of SM_1 = opportunity amount * Share1%)
- Share1% (share in percent, default is 100% for non split deals)
- SM_2
- Revenue2 (total revenue of SM_2 = opportunity amount * Share2%)
- Share2% (share in percent, default is 0%)
- SM_3
- Revenue3 (total revenue of SM_3 = opportunity amount * Share3%)
- Share3% (share in percent, default is 0%)

The data would look like this:

[image]

The report I want to create should show the total revenue for each SM - e.g. for Sales manager A = 5000 + 3000 + 2000 + 9000 = 19.000.

Is this possible to achieve?